# Angular 2 Route changing in nested component

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a fairly simple Angular 2 problem. I have a main view with  a toolbar at the top and a router outlet right below it.

**mainView.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pod-app',
    template: `
        <pod-toolbar></pod-toolbar>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- USE THIS router-outlet -->
    `,
    directives: [ ToolbarComponent, RouteComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
    providers: [
        EventService,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/list',
        name: 'ListView',
        component: ListViewComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/tileView',
        name: 'TileView',
        component: TileViewComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/pdfView',
        name: "PdfView",
        component: PdfViewComponent
    }
])

export class MainComponent implements OnInit { 
    ...blah...blah...blah
 }
```

Then I have my toolbar.ts which nested inside it is my route navigation list

**toolbar.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pod-toolbar',
    template: `
        <div class="demo-toolbar">
            <p>
                <md-toolbar color="primary">

                    <pod-routes></pod-routes> <!-- appRoutes.ts component -->

                </md-toolbar>
            </p>

        </div>
    `,
    directives: [MdToolbar, MdButton,RouteComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
    ...blah...blah...blah
}
```

Then Here is the route links that get nested inside the toolbar that need to change the view underneath the  toolbar in the mainView

**appRoutes.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'pod-routes',
    template: 
    `
        <nav>
            <a [routerLink]="['/ListView']"><img src="pathto.png" height="45" width="45"></a>
            <a [routerLink]="['/TileView']"><img src="pathto.png" height="40" width="45" ></a>
            <a [routerLink]="['/PdfView']"><img src="pathto.png" height="40" width="45" ></a>
        </nav>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class RouteComponent{

}
```

So, what am I doing wrong? This is the way I would like it set up but if this just isn't feasable then maybe I could move the routes into the toolbar and if that isn't feasable then I could just move the entire toolbar into the mainView, which I don't want to do but if I have to then I will.

**UPDATE**

Removed ROUTER_PROVIDERS from appRoutes.ts, still having same issue.

**UPDATE 2**

Added '/' to url routes at suggestion of answer, same issue, url in address bar changes but ui underneath the toolbar doesn't

**UPDATE 3**

Removed `providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` from toolbar.ts and mainView.ts files and bootstrapped `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in app.ts

```
bootstrap(MainComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}) ] )
     .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Seems to have done the trick. Many thanks to Gunter for sticking with me and helping me solve the issue. His Plunker really helped!

Comment: Do note that in the address bar the url changes correctly when I click the buttons just the ui doesn't change

Comment: Can you try a different browser?

Comment: I think you should remove the `@RouteConfig()` on `RouteComponent` or clarify which `<router-outlet>` should be used for the routes you navigate using the links in your question.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Gunter, I really appreciate it. Used FireFox instead of Chrome, same result. I also simplified the question and removed the `@RouteConfig` from appRoutes.ts to show desired implementation.

Comment: I added a Plunker link to my answer. I simplified it a bit. I had the `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in `bootstrap()` and left it there (removed from your code). Can you please try to reproduce your problem with this Plunker? I the Plunker you can't see the URL because it runs in an iframe but you see the view updating ;-)

Comment: Super, I have been working on getting a fiddle working but I guess you beat me to it. I will check it out.

Comment: Günter Thanks for all the help and sticking with me and working with me on this problem. See update 3 to see what fixed the issue

Comment: I guess this is why I kept `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in `bootstrap()` instead of moving it to the root component because the provider of `LocationStrategy` must come after `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` because it overrides the default `PathLocationStrategy` contained in `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` and for the purpose of overriding providers, order is significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update2**

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/hecd8B?p=preview)

**update**

Prefix the route names with `/` to tell that the root router should navigate to this route:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/ListView']"><img src="pathto.png" height="45" width="45"></a>
<a [routerLink]="['/TileView']"><img src="pathto.png" height="40" width="45" ></a>
<a [routerLink]="['/PdfView']"><img src="pathto.png" height="40" width="45" ></a>
```

**original**

Don't provide `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` more than once

```
providers: [
    EventService,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]
```

`ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should be provided exactly once at the root component and nowhere else (alternatively in `boostrap(...)`)

Comment: Ok, gotcha, removed ROUTER_PROVIDERS from my appRoutes.ts. Still having same issue but fixed code issue. Thanks dude!

Comment: I udpated my answer.

Comment: thanks Gunter, I have reflected your changes in the question but I am still having the same issue, that the url in the address bar is changing correctly but the ui doesn't update, it stays on the same html partial from initial load.